# Under what conditions does a matrix map the gradient of one function to another?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Let $M_{ij}(\mathbf{x})$ be a matrix depending on variables $\mathbf{x}$.  Under what conditions on $M_{ij}(\mathbf{x})$ do there exist functions $f(\mathbf{x})$ and $g(\mathbf{x})$ such that

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}= \sum_j M_{ij} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}$

and how can I find (all) such functions?

Comment: You mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}= \sum_{j=1}^nM_{ij} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}$ ? (Einstein convention is not widespread...)

Comment: That is what I mean - I will make the original clearer...